# Размеры картинок для дизайна приложения

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

1. Я рисую дизайн приложения в макс. разрешении 1242 х 2208. Для 6+ сидит идеально, тут всё ок.
   Мне нужно теперь, к примеру, элемент дизайна - картинку, создать для 6 айфона. Говорят, что нужно делить на 2, но разделив 1242 на 2, я не получу 750, как ширина у шестого айфона и также не получу 640, как у пятого айфона.

   Каким образом решается эта проблема на практике?
2. Я вставляю картинку в storyboard и хочу, чтобы она была ровно таким размером, каким она идет в оригинале и этот размер хочу задать жестко, мне предлагает задать размер в поинтах, но 100 поинтов в шестом айфоне и 100 поинтов в пятом айфоне выглядят по разному, из-за этого у меня проблема с неравномерными отступами и вообще внешним видом. Как это решается на практике? Если я ставлю позицию картинки, как centered, то это примерно её реальный размер, но тогда constraints высчитываются не от края самой картинки, а от края блока в котором находится картинка. Как сделать этот блок (4 точки белые по углам), чтобы он "седел" тютелька в тютельку на самой картинки, а не был чем-то абстрактным?
3. Слева картинка, справа текст, у картинки левый отступ от superview 5pt, создаю constraints, что расстояние между текстом и картинкой 15 поинтов. Если потом захожу в constraints текста и меняю расстояние на 25 поинтов, то картинка сужается, хотя "я не просил". Как сделать размер картинки неизменным в таком случае? Пусть текст залазит на картинку, пусть текст уходит в многоточие ..., но не сужает картинку. Размеры не могу задать из-за пункта 1 и 2 в моем вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Пункт 3 решил. Кому интересно: есть такие значения у элемента, например картинки, во вкладке линейке (size inspector) Content hugging priority и Content compression resistance priority. Так вот, у картинки оба эти значения поставил чуть выше (255 и 755) и теперь скорее любой другой элемент с низшим значением (приоритетом) будет сужаться/двигаться, но не картинка. Т.е. если вам нужно какой-то элемент, чтобы железобетонно стоял на своем месте, поиграйтесь с этими приоритетами.